# Cocoa Fullscreen problem with keyDown and keyUp

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl, fullscreen

I make fullscreen in this way:

```
NSRect frame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];

// Instantiate new borderless window
fullscreenWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                    styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                    backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer: NO];

startingWindow = [self window];
[startingWindow setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:NO];
[startingWindow orderOut:nil];

if(fullscreenWindow != nil)
{
    // Set the options for our new fullscreen window         
    [fullscreenWindow setReleasedWhenClosed: YES];
    [fullscreenWindow setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
    [fullscreenWindow setContentView: self];
    [fullscreenWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self ];
    [fullscreenWindow setLevel: NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel-1];
    [fullscreenWindow makeFirstResponder:self];
}
```

After switching to fullscreen not working keyDown and keyUp.
What to do to make it working?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards Chudziutki

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the NSWindow class with your own class that inherits from NSWindow. Then you override the keyDown and keyUp event messages in order to capture them. You then pass these events to whoever needs them.

Comment: Yes, I must to override NSWindow but there is only need to set -(BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow { return YES; }. Many thanks, to show direction :).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing all this work yourself?  Just send your view an `-enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:` message.

Comment: I not use this because I can't set window level  "NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel-1". I try set this with options "NSFullScreenModeWindowLevel" or after use this function by setLevel, but both of this not work.